# Solving a recurrence with exponential rule where master theorem does not apply

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I am trying to solve the following recurrence:

```
$T(n) = 3T(n^{\frac{2}{3}}) + \log n$
```

but am not sure how to do so, since Master theorem does not apply. I tried to draw the recursion tree as follows:
[image]

but am not sure where to go from there, such as trying to figure out the height of the tree or the number of nodes in the last layer. Any guidance on how to find the overall big theta of the recurrence would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you expand the formula, we will have:

```
T(n) = 3 log(n^{2/3}) +‌ 3^2 log(n^((2/3)^2)) + ... + 3^k log(n^((2/3)^k)) + log(n)
```

In the above equation, `k` is the height of the tree. If we suppose `n = 2 ^ ((3/2)^k)`, finally we will have `2` in `n^((2/3)^k)`. Hence, `k = log_{3/2)(log(n))`.  Also, we know that `log(n^a) = a log(n)`:

```
T(n) = 2 log(n) + 2^2 log(n) + ... + 2^k log(n) + log(n) = 
         log(n) (1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^k) =
         (2^(k+1) - 1) log(n)
```

Hence, as `2^k = O(log^2(n))`,  `T(n) = O(log^2(n) * log(n)) = \O(log^3(n))`.

Comment: The base of the outer logarithm in `k = log_{3/2}(log(n))` should be taken into account

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks for your notice. Normally, if it is not mentioned, it will be `log_2` and here is the same.